# Get SQS URL from within Serverless function?

Tags: amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm building a Serverless app that defines an SQS queue in the resources as follows:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    TheQueue:
      Type: "AWS:SQS:Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "TheQueue"
```

I want to send messages to this queue from within one of the functions. How can I access the URL from within the function? I want to place it here:

```
const params = {
    MessageBody: 'message body here',
    QueueUrl: 'WHATS_THE_URL_HERE',
    DelaySeconds: 5
};
```

Answer (score 31):

This is a great question!

I like to set the queue URL as an ENV var for my app!

So you've named the queue `TheQueue`.

Simply add this snippet to your `serverless.yml` file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: <YOUR RUNTIME>
  environment:
    THE_QUEUE_URL: { Ref: TheQueue }
```

Serverless will automatically grab the queue URL from your CloudFormation and inject it into your ENV.

Then you can access the param as:

```
const params = {
    MessageBody: 'message body here',
    QueueUrl: process.env.THE_QUEUE_URL,
    DelaySeconds: 5
};
```

Comment: Great, it helped me after I failed several times with GetAtt and Url and QueueUrl :). Why does a queue have no Url attribute?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Get Queue URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html) API, though I tend to also pass it in to my function. The `QueueUrl` is the `Ref` value for an SQS queue in CloudFormation, so you can pretty easily get to it in your CloudFormation. [This handy cheat sheet](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/) is really helpful for working with CloudFormation attributes and refs.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see where it say what @Aaron Stuyvenberg answered above.

Answer (score 1):

I go a bit of a different route. I, personally, don't like storing information in environment variables when using lambda, though I really like Aaron Stuyvenberg solution. Therefore, I store information like this is AWS SSM Parameter store.

Then in my code I just call for it when needed. Forgive my JS it has been a while since I did it. I mostly do python

```
var ssm = new AWS.SSM();
const myHandler = (event, context) => {
    var { Value } = await ssm.getParameter({Name: 'some.name.of.parameter'}).promise()

    const params = {
        MessageBody: 'message body here',
        QueueUrl: Value,
        DelaySeconds: 5
    };
}
```

There is probably some deconstruction of the returned data structure I got wrong, but this is roughly what I do. In python I wrote a library that does all of this with one line.